# Simple Typed.js And React.useEffect() Not Running in Astro Project

Tags: reactjs, astrojs, typedjs

I have scoured the internet for solutions to this problem and have been scratching my head for 2 or 3 days now trying to figure out why this simple piece of code is not working as intended.

Source:

```
const Hero = () => {
  const el = React.useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const typed = new Typed(el.current, {
      strings: ['<i>First</i> sentence.', '&amp; a second sentence.'],
      typeSpeed: 50,
    });

    return () => {
      typed.destroy();
    };
  });
  return (
    <Section>
      <div className="">
        <span ref={el} />
      </div>
    </Section>
  );
};
export { Hero };
```

`Hero` is a partial that I import into a `.astro` file to be part of my home page. I ripped the example right off the Typed.js GitHub. `Section` is another component that sets the view port of the page.

It seems that the `useEffect` hook is not called at all. `console.log` inside of it never prints anything. Am I missing something? These are obviously React components, React is installed in my project and the `@astro/react` adapter is also installed (and is imported into the `astro.config.mjs` as an integration).

Does this have something to do with Astro's static nature? SSR vs. CSR? I have been digging into this for too long and I am at a loss. Help is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You're missing useEffect's dependencies

Comment: @JeffreyRam As per Typed.js documentation, an empty array is meant to work in their simple example. In the code in the post I have no array, but I have tried it with an empty array as well and it still doesnt work. My understanding is that the dependencies array is optional to begin with, as per React documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include your component in an `.astro` file like this:

```
<Hero client:load />
```

Without a `client` directive, Astro will only server-side render the component and not hydrate it, see [Astro's framework components docs](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/framework-components/#hydrating-interactive-components).

(And make sure to save the file itself as `Hero.tsx`)

Comment: So simple, and yet I spent so long trying to figure this out... As you can tell, front end is not my strongest skill lol. Thanks for the help, it worked immediately after I added this!